# Reading specific line from string

Tags: python, string, line

I'm trying to read the content of specific lines in a string stored as a variable. However I only know how to find it if it looks through a file, which would be like this:

```
line = dayresult.readlines()
print line[3]
```

The string I'm looking for is taken from a file, but I only know the content's position in the string, but not in the file itself, due to how large it is, and it will change each day.

So if anyone knows how to store the content on a specific line in the string as a variable that would be great.

EDIT: I'm trying to get a certain line in a string that is currently being stored as a variable. I need the content on specific line numbers, and only those.

Comment: Is there a part of the content your looking for that always stays constant? You could do `for l in lines: if (constant part) in l: print l`

Comment: Thanks, but the content I'm looking for isn't constant, the line number it'll be on is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I understand what you're trying to do. "readlines" gives you a list of strings/lines. So now you got the whole file as a list of lines. But as far as I understand, you only know the position of the information you want in a line, but you don't know what line you're looking for?

I think you're looking for:

```
with open(filename, "r") as file_variable:
       for line in file_variable:
             #look for your content in each line
```

Edit:
The answer is:

```
import re
....
re.split("\n", file_variable)
```

Comment: Let me try to elaborate: 
The string I'm looking for is taken from a file, but it is stored as a variable. I can't look through the entire file. The content I'm looking for is always on the specific lines, and I need to get that content, but only the content on that line.

Comment: So the file is somehow read into a variable, but not stored line by line and you can't go through it line by line. Do you have something that seperates the lines, like a "\n"? Then you could do a "split" on the file_variable and have it stored line by line.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bkqwxh6M
This is the string I'm trying to read the lines of. I want the first line to be stored a one variable, the second one to be stored as another variable etc. And this is from a variable already created in the script.

Comment: Ok, so you got that string, but what do you see as a "line" in that? If that string is in a line in a file it's one line, if every word of the string comes from a separate line in a file it's #words lines. If the string was separated by sentences it could have been 2 lines.
Edit: Ah, ok...the link was shown just now. But if the original file looked like that the string has to contain "\n"s, or some other separator.

Comment: Not quite that you saw my edit, but I made a pastebin.  http://pastebin.com/bkqwxh6M

This is what I mean by lines. I want everything on line 1 to be stored as a variable and everything on line 2 to be stored as a variable

Comment: If you print the variable, does it show the same line separation in your output? Because than it really should be as easy as
"
import re, 
lines = re.split("\n", variable)
"

Comment: Yes I do have the same line separation if I print the variable

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly :D

Comment: Glad it worked. Edited the answer. Please mark it as accepted :)